# How can I use YAML objects from docker-compose as variables in DockerFile and scripts

Tags: mongodb, docker, yaml, docker-compose

In trying to make a nice testing lab docker-compose yaml I have run into a case where I would want to have something like:

```
rs1-node1:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:1234
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        replset:"rs1"
rs1-node2:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:1234
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        replset:"rs1"
rs1-node3:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:1234
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        replset:"rs1"
rs2-node1:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:1235
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        replset:"rs2"
rs2-node2:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:1235
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        replset:"rs2"
rs2-node3:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:1235
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        replset:"rs2"
config1:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:2234
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        configsvr:"true"
        replset:"config"
config2:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:2234
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        configsvr:"true"
        replset:"config"
config3:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
        port:2234
        auth:"true"
        keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
        configsvr:"true"
        replset:"config"
mongos:
    image: "davidbmurphy/percona_mongodb:3.0"
    config: 
       configdb: "config1:2234,config2:2234,config3:2234"
       port:27017
       auth:"true"
       keyfile="{{$KEY_FILE}}"
```

As you can see for each node, there is a "config" object which is the overrides I would like to drop eventually into  /etc/mongodb.conf inside the container. The trick here as they are many optional variables especially when you consider MongoDB now supports multiple engines and Percona is adding, even more, engines by default having a list of ENV variables could be very expensive.

My question:

How can I pass .config into docker, and then into the dockerFile, so I could tell it or another script to write out /etc/mongod.conf based on that variable. I could always write out configs and copy them into the container, but that seems messy, as is trying to have 50+ conditionals for every variable that exists in the mongo configuration file options.

Comment: You could just write a small python program that parses the `docker-compose.yml` file and writes out the appropriate values to a file and then invokes `docker-compose`. Or, since your configs are so similar use my docker-compose-wrapper ([ruamel.dcw](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.dcw/)) and call that with the appropriate environment variables set to provide for the differences for each node (ruamel.dcw does write out a configuration file that you then can use in your Dockerfile)

Comment: Also realise that your example is invalid YAML. The last `config` key (for `mongos`, does have a string scalar as argument, but starts with a mapping (because of the space after `configdb:` and then continues with a non-key scalar (`port:27017`) on the next line.